# How to fill and add text in a text field with drop down selections

Tags: javascript

I'm not a coder ut I've found this code here

http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/kchRh/

```
<textarea id="mytext"></textarea>

<select id="dropdown">
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="text1">text1</option>
    <option value="text2">text2</option>
    <option value="text3">text3</option>
    <option value="text4">text4</option>
</select>

var mytextbox = document.getElementById('mytext');
var mydropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');

mydropdown.onchange = function(){
     mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value  + this.value;
}
```

I'd like to modify it so that I've more than one dropdown and each one add his text in the same field.

Practically I'd have to create a compact code easily for the user so that the user select some phrases using the dropdown and the code will fill the text field.

If I can be more precise please let me know. As said Iìm not a coder so if you can write down the code to use I'll be very happy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a js bin with multiple dropdowns' onchange event being listed to: https://jsfiddle.net/kchRh/944/

You want to give the dropdowns class names and then loop through each drop down to setup their listeners.

HTML:

```
<textarea id="mytext"></textarea>

<select class="dropdown">
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="text1">text1</option>
    <option value="text2">text2</option>
    <option value="text3">text3</option>
    <option value="text4">text4</option>
</select>

<select class="dropdown">
    <option value="">2None</option>
    <option value="2text1">2text1</option>
    <option value="2text2">2text2</option>
    <option value="2text3">2text3</option>
    <option value="2text4">2text4</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
var mytextbox = document.getElementById('mytext');
var mydropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown');

for(i=0;i<mydropdowns.length;i++) {
    mydropdowns[i].onchange = function(){
         mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value  + this.value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following approach:

```
// create a reusable function:
function updateTextArea() {
  // get all the elements with the class 'dropdown':
  var selectElems = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown'),
      // get the <textarea> element, using its id: 
      textArea = document.getElementById('mytext'),
      // using Array.prototype.filter on the array-like
      // NodeList, using Function.prototype.call, in
      // order to iterate over the found '.dropdown'
      // elements to form an array of only those elements
      // with a non-zero-length value:
      values = Array.prototype.filter.call(selectElems, function(el) {
      if (el.value.trim().length) {
        return el.value;
      }
    // iterating over the filter-created array, to form a map of
    // the selected values of the elements:
    }).map(function(el) {
      return el.value;
    // joining those arrays together, with Array.prototype.join,
    // to form a comma-separated string of values, and appending
    // a period:
    }).join(', ') + '.';

  // setting the value of the <textarea> to:
  // - an empty string (if the values variable is
  // just the appended-period), or to the value of
  // the values variable:
  textArea.value = values === '.' ? '' : values;
}

// as above, retrieving the '.dropdown' elements:
var selects = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown');

// iterating over the '.dropdown' elements, using
// Array.prototype.forEach:
Array.prototype.forEach.call(selects, function(el, index, arr) {
  // within the anonymous function of Array.prototype.foreach:
  // the first argument (here: 'el') is the current array-element,
  // second argument (here: 'index') is the index of the current
  // array-element within the array over which we're iterating,
  // third argument (here: 'arr') is the array over which we're
  // iterating.

  // binding updateTextArea as the change event-handler for
  // each of the array-elements over which we iterate:
  el.addEventListener('change', updateTextArea);
});
```

```js
function updateTextArea() {
  var selectElems = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown'),
    textArea = document.getElementById('mytext'),
    values = Array.prototype.filter.call(selectElems, function(el) {
      if (el.value.trim().length) {
        return el.value;
      }
    }).map(function(el) {
      return el.value;
    }).join(', ') + '.';

  textArea.value = values === '.' ? '' : values;
}

var selects = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(selects, function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('change', updateTextArea);
});
```

```html
<textarea id="mytext"></textarea>
<select class="dropdown">
  <option value="">None</option>
  <option value="text1">text1</option>
  <option value="text2">text2</option>
  <option value="text3">text3</option>
  <option value="text4">text4</option>
</select>
<select class="dropdown">
  <option value="">None</option>
  <option value="text5">text5</option>
  <option value="text6">text6</option>
  <option value="text7">text7</option>
  <option value="text8">text8</option>
</select>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kchRh/946/).

Note, in the HTML, I've changed from the use of `id` to identify the `<select>` elements, to using `class`; simply because it allows a group of elements to be associated together without having to use a large number of `id`s and subsequently having to update the JavaScript in turn with the HTML.

Referencs:

- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).
- [`eventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).